# How do I insert special characters to an HTML iframe document?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, sandbox

I am trying to add JavaScript to an HTML sandbox iframe.
The JavaScript code contains a strange character.
When the code is run outside of an iframe, it works perfectly.
Unfortunately, though, Stack Overflow cannot display this character.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <body>
        <script>
            console.log("Special character: ''")
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now I want to insert this code into a sandbox iframe using srcdoc.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <body>
        <iframe sandbox = "allow-scripts" srcdoc = "<!DOCTYPE html><body><script>console.log(Special character: '')</script></body></html>"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I run the code above in the Firefox web browser, it sometimes displays the character in the console.
At other times, it raises an error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: invalid range in character class`.
The main reason why this is odd is because the result is different each time.
This made me wonder if it was a Firefox bug. Please explain the reason for this.

After spending a lot of time on this, I decided to take another approach.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <body>
        <iframe id = frame sandbox = "allow-scripts allow-same-origin"></iframe>

        <script>
            const content = frame.contentWindow || frame.contentDocument
            content.document.open()
            content.document.write("<!DOCTYPE html><body><script>console.log(Special character: '')<\/script></body></html>")
            content.document.close()
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This time, I get a different error: `missing ) after argument list`. I know that no brackets are missing. The thing causing the problem is the special character.

Finally, I tried something else.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <body>
        <iframe id = frame sandbox = "allow-scripts allow-same-origin"></iframe>

        <script>
            const content = frame.contentWindow || frame.contentDocument
            content.document.open()
            content.document.write("<!DOCTYPE html><body></body></html>")
            content.document.close()

            content.eval("console.log(Special character: '')")
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The code above sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.
This is very frustrating.
Another problem with the code above is that I have to include `allow-same-origin` in the iframe sandbox, I want the iframe to be as secure as possible and I don't really want to give the iframe too much control.

Is this just a Firefox bug? Even if I can't display this character in the console, how can I ensure that no errors occur?

**Edit:**
Stack Overflow keeps removing the character from my post.
Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Grey41/79ksqt4L/4) instead.

Comment: For clarification, I have tried this test on a few special characters. They don’t seem to have any significance individually.

Comment: Need to understand why your "special characters" are not showing in SO. SO is fully Unicode compliant. Can you paste it here or in your question?

Comment: Sorry, I can't. Please view the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Grey41/79ksqt4L/4).

Comment: From your JSFiddle, it's `0x1C`, in UTF-8 that's `INFORMATION SEPARATOR FOUR`: https://www.cogsci.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=0x1c&mode=bytes - you can entitize it in HTML as `&#x0001C;`

Comment: U+001C is a control character. Control characters usually do not have a visible glyph. How then do you know what it should look like? How did you determine that what was showing outside the IFRAME is the correct version? In fact, U+001C has the Unicode property Whitespace set to true, so any rendering that doesn't look like a space is most likely incorrect. Maybe if you explain why you need this character in a string, we can understand your problem better and help find a solution.

Comment: If you really need to insert that character, and you are the one creating the string, just use `"\x1c" and it will always be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the helpful comments.
This is not a Firefox bug.
When you are dealing with special characters, you can't just paste them as plain HTML. Also, I was making a big mistake. I was writing the following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <body>
        <iframe access = "allow-scripts" srcdoc = "<!DOCTYPE html><body><script>console.log(Special character: '')</script></body></html>"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you look closely, you will see that I was missing the quotes in the `console.log` function. This caused a JavaScript error. The JavaScript `charCodeAt()` function is useful for getting the character code, [@Old Geezer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/936293/old-geezer) helped me to understand this.

After you have the character code, you can then write the HTML code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <body>
        <iframe access = "allow-scripts" srcdoc = "<!DOCTYPE html><body><script>console.log(&#34;Special character: '&#28;'&#34;)</script></body></html>"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

The code above runs without any errors. The fact that the character is displayed differently on different browsers is not a problem because this specific character doesn't have a visible glyph.

Comment: Does this work: `... srcDoc="...<script>console.log('\x28')</script> ... "` ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant `'\x1c'`.

Comment: Yes, this works. Writing the character code in the JavaScript string is neater than writing the html code.